# org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException in selenium web driver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For the html code it's showing button but it is Input.

```
<input id="cmdExport" type="submit" value="Save File" onmouseover="return MVstyle()" onmouseout="return MOstyle()" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 20px; width: 100px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer;">
```

In selenium webdriver i used below code it's not working.

```
WebElement saveButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@id='cmdExport']"));
                saveButton.click();
```

Also i tried with

```
new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible("cmdExport");
                WebElement saveButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@id='cmdExport']")).sendKeys("TEXT");
                saveButton.click();
```

Also tried below code not working please help

```
WebElement saveButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions
      .presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("cmdExport")));
```

I tried to post the complete htmlit's very big not able to post.

```
function MVstyle(){
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.cursor="pointer";
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.background="#66FF99";
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.border.radius="10px";
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.boxShadow="0px 0px 10px gray";
            };

            function MOstyle(){
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.background="";
              document.getElementById("cmdExport").style.boxShadow="";
            };


                //get parameters
                var params = {};
                if (location.search) {
                    var parts = location.search.substring(1).split('&');
                    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        var nv = parts[i].split('=');
                        if (!nv[0]) continue;
                        params[nv[0]] = nv[1];
                    }
                }
                console.log('appId', params.appId);  
                console.log('objectId', params.objectId);  

                d = new Date();
                var dstring = d.valueOf();          
                var fileName = params.objectId+'_'+dstring;

                //open apps
                var app = qlik.openApp(params.appId, config);

                app.getObject('QV01',params.objectId).then( function( vizModel ) { 
                    $('#cmdExport').show(); 
                    $('#cmdExport').on('click', function() {  
                        vizModel.exportData('CSV_C','/qHyperCubeDef',fileName,'A').then(function( reply ) { 
                            document.getElementById("fileLocation").href=reply.result.qUrl;
                            $("#fileLocation").show();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
    </script>
    <style>
            article.qvobject
            {
                position:absolute;
                overflow: hidden;
                padding: 10px;
            }
    </style>

    <body style="overflow:auto" class="">
    <form style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </form>

    <input id="cmdExport" type="submit" value="Save File" onmouseover="return MVstyle()" onmouseout="return MOstyle()" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 20px; width: 100px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer;" class="xh-highlight">
    <a id="fileLocation" href="/tempcontent/e1d54811-d730-43d9-8114-6580793f6b1b/4003a0a9-bb23-4dc9-8568-9351a3770233.csv?serverNodeId=fd4d9fdf-d8be-4d1b-b176-8a8c3ac6bbe8" style="" ;="">Download Link</a> 
    <div id="QV01" style="position: absolute; top: 30px; left: 180px; width: 600px; height: 400px;" class="qvobject"><div class="qv-object-wrapper ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" model="model" options="options">
```

Comment: There where two elements related to button first one was shown without hovering mouse and other gets shown when i hover mouse over button. Element shown on hovering mouse was performing actual function using a javascript and that element was not visible until i hover mouse over button .Clicking on that directly was giving ElementNotVisibleException. This is the problem, how can i find that second element.

Answer (score 0):

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException occurs when the element is loaded in the DOM but is not visible to be interaced with. In your case most possible scenario might be, having multiple element with the same id `cmdExport`. So Selenium is getting the first element with the same id (which is hidden) from DOM and fires the action against it.

Try finding the number of elements which are returned for the path locator.

```
List<WebElement> saveButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@id='cmdExport']"));
```

The above code will return all the elements which matches the xpath `//input[@id='cmdExport']`

If the list size is more than one that means you are having multiple web elements which matches the given xpath. If so you have to write the xpath more uniquely to target the required element.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 : Use Actions class:

```
        WebElement saveButton = driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@id='cmdExport']"));

        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.click(saveButton).perform();
```

Option 2 : Inject Javascript

```
      ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", saveButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do the trick:

```
WebElement hoverElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("input[@id='cmdExport']"));
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.moveToElement(hoverElement).perform();
By locator = By.id("fileLocation");
driver.click(locator);
```

it will locate the element, hover over it that will make "a" tag visible and will click on "a" tag.

I hope this helps.

Comment: if you post the relevant HTML here I will be able to help you.

Comment: <body style="overflow:auto" class="">
<form style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left: 20px;" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
</form>

<input id="cmdExport" type="submit" value="Save File" onmouseover="return MVstyle()" onmouseout="return MOstyle()" style="position: absolute; top: 50px; left: 20px; width: 100px; height: 30px; cursor: pointer;" class="xh-highlight">
<a id="fileLocation" href="/tempcontent/e1d54811-d730-43d9-8114-

Comment: Can you please provide both elements. Here I can see that there is only one element. And I can see that hovering on it will make available another element that holds the function that you want to run. So I need at least both elements please.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below locator

```
By.xpath("(//a[@id='cmdExport'])[1]")   //for accessing second element
```

As you mentioned in your comment,

- mouseOver on that element
- Then click

Look at [this](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2012/04/mouseover-method-in-webdriver.html) for mouseOver method.